# переменная созданная в функции видна другой функции?

Tags: python

```
def coor():
    x=20
def coor1():
    x+=1
    print(x)
coor()
```

Мне нужно чтобы из coor1 вывелся x. Я понимаю свою ошибку, но не в силах исправить. Как сделать так, чтобы переменная созданная в функции была видна другой функции?

Comment: лучше так не делать... Пусть одна функция возвращает значение (`return ...`), а другая функция вызывает первую...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция имеет свою область видимости, поэтому когда вы создаете переменную в функции, эта переменная доступна только этой функции и считается локальной. Если вы хотите дать доступ к переменной из нескольких функций, вы можете создать эту переменную в общей зоне видимости ваших функций, но если вы хотите явно изменить существующую переменную, вам необходимо указать это с помощью `global`:

```
x = 10
def coor():
    global x  # для изменения глобальной переменной необходимо уточнить, что она будет изменяться
    x=20
    return x

def coor1(x):
    x+=1
    print(x)  # тут мы распечатаем х+1, однако х не изменится

coor()
```

Или передавать переменную явно каждой функции и сохранять результат в новую переменную:

```
def coor(x):
    x=20
    return x

def coor1(x):
    x+=1
    print(x)
    return x

x = coor(20)  # х - переменная, значением которой является выполнение функции coor
xx = coor1(x)  # х по прежнему равен 20, хх равен 21 - результат выполнения coor1
```

Читайте про область видимости. Хорошим вариантом будет оставить глобальную зону видимости и сгруппировать функции и переменные в одном месте - в классе:

```
>>> class A():
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.x = 20
...   def c(self):
...     self.x = 10
...   def b(self):
...     self.x += 1
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.x
20
>>> a.c()
>>> a.x
10
>>> a.b()
>>> a.x
11
>>> a.b()
>>> a.x
12
>>> a.b()
>>> a.x
13
```

Comment: по-моему лучше первую часть с `global` вообще убрать. `global` вообще редко когда действительно необходимо, а для начинающих (я про автора вопроса) лучше вообще не использовать...

Comment: Согласен, но я думаю для примера изменения и не изменения данных в зоне видимости функции это полезно

Comment: первый пример кода сломанный. По ссылке вверху указано почему.

Comment: @jfs да, упустил аргумент, исправил

Comment: @IgorLavrynenko теперь, к чему global оставлять, если вы явно через параметр передаёте x? В чём отличие от второго примера?

Comment: @jfs там, где есть `global` я не передаю переменную

Comment: @IgorLavrynenko и какое это отношение к вопросу имеет? Прочитайте заголовок, каким образом ваш пример на него отвечает?

Comment: @jfs так лучше?

Comment: просто уберите первый пример (monstrosity). global здесь вообще никак не помогает значение в coor1() передать.

Answer (score 0):

@MaxU предложил лучший вариант:

```
def coor():
    return 20


def coor1():
    c = coor()
    print(c+1)


coor1()
```